# phonegap + facebook plugin: login opens browser instead of popup (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I'm building a phonegap app with facebook authentication (https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect). I already have it working on android, but on iOS, I'm having this issue:

When I click 'login' (on the example index.html provided by the plugin), it opens a browser window and goes to facebook's mobile login page, instead of opening the facebook login dialog in a popup.

[image]

However, when I click 'wall post', it does open the expected popup (although it also seems buggy, login does not seem to work).

What can I do to make sure the popup opens for the login dialog, and not the browser?

Cheers,

Hoff

Comment: Possible duplicate of : 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130073/facebook-authentication-with-new-facebook-sdk-for-ios-vs-old-facebook-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now the default behaviour for FBConnect when the device supports multi-tasking but does not have the FB app installed. The popup is only used on devices that do not support multi-tasking.

If you really want the popup you will have to go in to the FBConnect code and change it so that it always uses FBDialog.

The behaviour is documented here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso

Comment: thanks, makes sense - could you point me to where this is documented please?

Comment: Document link is broken.